# LockAcquisition exceptions even on Connection isolation UNCOMMITTED READ

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

We have been dealing with `LockAcquisitionException`s or `Lock wait timeout exceeded` and as we don't need any locking protection - it is much more crucial to get *some* response even if it is not fully consistent. For this reason, I have tried to set `UNCOMMITTED READ` for connection isolation. However this did not help and we keep getting these exceptions.

There can be two things:

- My `UNCOMMITTED READ` setting is ignored. I tried to programmatically find Hibernate properties within the running application and it was correctly set to `1`, so this shouldn't be the case.
- Something else is causing these exceptions.

Can you elaborate how I can investigate more?